# How to read until end of file C, fscanf

Tags: c, file, eof

What i read from a file: a P1/ s/ e/ t etc. / for different line. After specific letters(like 'a') come some data i have to collect so i don't want to use fgets. It doesn't end running. Could you help me, please?

```
char com[21];
fscanf(src,"%s",com);
while(com!=EOF)
{
    if(com[0]=='a')
        fprintf(dest,"%s 1",com);
     if(com[0]=='s')
        fprintf(dest,"%s 2",com);
    fscanf(src,"%s",com);
}
```

Comment: You don't give a satisfactory reason why you don't want to use `fgets`. It will be much easier to examine the input data as a string, than serially with `scanf` family. But one way you can check for end of file is by testing the function return value from `fscanf(src,"%s",com);` which you should be doing anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way is to test if `fscanf()` succeeded as the loop condition and you don't need a `fscanf()` before the loop:

```
char com[21];

while(fscanf(src,"%20s",com) == 1)
{
    if(com[0]=='a')
        fprintf(dest,"%s 1",com);
     if(com[0]=='s')
        fprintf(dest,"%s 2",com);
}
```

`fscanf()` returns the number of items successfully scanned. So, you don't need to check if it' returned `EOF`.

Note that I changed the format string to avoid buffer overflow. I suggest you use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html) instead of `fscanf()` (and remember to take care of newline chars if it matters).

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `fscanf` returns an `integer` which can indicate `EOF` when the End of File is reached. Please refer to the man pages for more detail.

Your code will have to modified like below:

```
char com[21];
int ret;
ret = fscanf(src,"%s",com);
while(ret!=EOF)
{
    if(com[0]=='a')
        fprintf(dest,"%s 1",com);
     if(com[0]=='s')
        fprintf(dest,"%s 2",com);
    ret = fscanf(src,"%s",com);
}
```